# Freezing Scenekit Simulation

Tags: ios, scenekit, physics-engine

This is more a general question, I cannot really assign it specifically.
While still working on my spaceship game, I noticed recently that the Scenekit simulation freezes when the ship (which is controlled by the player) is not moving. All control buttons are inactive from that instance on. At first I was thinking that the app crashed, but then I found out that after double-click on the iPad-button and jumping into the app again gives me a second or two of functioning controls. During these 1 or 2 seconds, the app seems to make up for the ‚frozen time‘, meaning the movements are rushing, until the app freezes again.
I circumvented the issue by a simple up-down-Sinus movement that I wanted to implement anyway. As Long as the ship is moving, no freezing is observed.
I think there is some issue in the multi-tasking of my iPad-device rather than an actual issue of my app.
Did anyone face similar problems, maybe because of the newest IOS, or even previous versions?

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

```
sceneView.rendersContinuously = true
```

By default this value is `false`, that means, that if there are no moving object anymore on scene, the renderer takes kind of a break, until there is moving something again. Hope I could help.

Comment: Thanks, ZAY. If the renderer takes that break, does this usually mean that everything else freezes as well? Because when this happens, all other functions (as button-pressing) aren't working anymore...

Comment: I just don't know. To which view do you add your UI Elements? To the main view or to the SCNView? if added to the SCNView, then probably yes. I nEver tested this. Usually I add such stuff to the Main View.